# Amazon SQS Messages not deleting in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I list the messages in my Amazon SQS queue and then have the option to delete them, one at a time. When I delete the message I get a SUCCESS message back. However, not a single message is deleted and they all return to the queue.

Here is the list queue code:

```
<?php
include_once("sdk.class.php");

// Instantiate
$sqs = new AmazonSQS();
$rows = $sqs->get_queue_size('https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/199992002821/SomeQueueSQS');

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=20 valign=top bgcolor=" . $adHeading . " align=left><strong>No</strong></td>";
echo "<td width=200 valign=top bgcolor=" . $adHeading . " align=left><strong>Message</strong></td>";
echo "<td width=50 align='right' bgcolor=" . $adHeading . "><a href='sqs.php'><img src='images/icon_refresh.png' border='0'></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
  {

    // Get Message
    $response = $sqs->receive_message('https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/199992002821/SomeQueueSQS', array(
  'VisibilityTimeout' => 30
));
$body = $response->body->ReceiveMessageResult->Message[0]->Body;
$rcpt_hand=($response->body->ReceiveMessageResult->Message[0]->ReceiptHandle);

    $id = $j + 1;

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td valign=top bgcolor=" . $bgcolor . ">$id</td>";
    echo "<td valign=top bgcolor=" . $bgcolor . ">$body</td>";
    echo "<td valign=top><a href=sqsdelete.php?sid=$rcpt_hand><img   src=images/icon_delete.gif border=0 width=18 height=18></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

  }

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Here is the delete code:

```
<?php

if ($response = $sqs->delete_message('https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/199992002821/SomeQueueSQS', $rcpt_hand)) {
  echo "Message deleted<br>";
} else {
  echo "Message not deleted<br>";
}

// Get list of unprocessed and valid messages
$rows = $sqs->get_queue_size('https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/199992002821/SomeQueueSQS');

echo "<table>";
etc...
```

Thanks

Andre

Answer (score 1):

The `if()` condition in your delete code is wrong. Your condition will *always* return true.

You need to make the request, then check if `$response->isOK()` is `true` or `false`. If the request was completed successfully, AWS will return a `2xx` status code, and the `isOK()` method will return `true`.

If you make that change and start seeing failures, use `print_r($response->body)` to view the error message that SQS is sending back. That should help you debug.